# Why does a decimal number with a 0 before it produce a SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, decimal, language-specifications

I was writing some Javascript when I accidentally typed `04.5` instead of `40.5`. When I ran the code, it produced a SyntaxError that read `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number`. I tested this in Chrome, Safari, Firefox, and NodeJS, and they all produced the same error. I looked through the [Javascript specifications](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf), but I couldn't find anything on it. What is Javascript interpreting a decimal number with a 0 before it as?

```js
04.5 // Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number
```

Comment: Maybe its interpreting it as a boolean (false)

Comment: Maybe it is interpreted as hexadecimal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a leading zero it's interpreted as octal. But it seems that octals are not liked with decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the leading zeros. This works fine:

```
JSON.parse('[04.5]');
```

JSON definition says **integers must not have leading zeros**

EDIT To remove the leading zeros in case you have an array of numbers starting with 0 :

```
var str = '[04,05,06,07,08,09]';
str = str.replace(/\b0(\d)/g, "$1");
JSON.parse(str);
```

Comment: but `04` works fine

Comment: The question is about JavaScript, not JSON

Comment: Right ! See the answer before !